# Weird collision detection with Snake Game

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, collision-detection

I am experiencing a weird collision detection bug that I am failing to find. I am building a small snake game, and as tradition goes, I need the snake to die when he collides with himself. So I told the snake head to die if it collides with any segment other than the first three. But It keeps throwing the collision even though there obviously isn't a collision.. I made the code completely stand alone for anyone that wants to see for themselves:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
run=True
prevpos=(0,0)
curid=0
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
points=0
def DrawSeg(x,y,col,size):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, col, (x,y), size, 0)
class HeadSegment(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.direct=(0,0)
        self.prevpos=(self.x,self.y)
        self.time=2
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x-5,self.y-5,10,10)
    def update(self):
        global segs
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x-5,self.y-5,10,10)
        self.time-=1
        for s in segs[5:]:
            if self.rect.colliderect(s.rect):
                print 'die'
        if self.time==0:
            self.time=2
            self.prevpos=(self.x,self.y)
        key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[K_LEFT]:
            if self.direct != (3,0):
                self.direct=(-3,0)
        elif key[K_RIGHT]:
            if self.direct != (-3,0):
                self.direct=(3,0)
        elif key[K_UP]:
            if self.direct != (0,3):
                self.direct=(0,-3)
        elif key[K_DOWN]:
            if self.direct != (0,-3):
                self.direct=(0,3)
        self.x+=self.direct[0]
        self.y+=self.direct[1]
        DrawSeg(self.x,self.y,(255,0,0),5)
head=HeadSegment(20,20)
class Segment(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        global curid
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.direct=(0,0)
        self.id=curid+1
        curid+=1
        self.prevpos=(self.x,self.y)
        self.time=2
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x-5,self.y-5,10,10)
    def update(self):
        self.time-=1
        if self.time==0:
            self.time=2
            self.prevpos=(self.x,self.y)
        global segs
        try:
            nextpos=segs[self.id+1]
            self.x=nextpos.prevpos[0]
            self.y=nextpos.prevpos[1]
        except:
            self.x=head.prevpos[0]
            self.y=head.prevpos[1]
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x-5,self.y-5,10,10)
        DrawSeg(self.x,self.y,(200,0,0),5)
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=randint(7,315)
        self.y=randint(7,235)
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x-6,self.y-6,12,12)
    def update(self):
        global points
        global segs
        DrawSeg(self.x,self.y,(0,0,220),6)
        if self.rect.colliderect(head.rect):
            self.x=randint(7,315)
            self.y=randint(7,235)
            self.rect=pygame.Rect(self.x-6,self.y-6,12,12)
            points+=1
            try:
                segs.append(Segment(segs[len(segs)-1].prevpos[0],segs[len(segs)-1].prevpos[1]))
            except:
                segs.append(Segment(20,20))

segs=[]
fruit=Fruit()
while run:
    screen.fill((0,200,0))
    for s in segs:
        s.update()
    fruit.update()
    head.update()
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            exit()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Can someone point out what is wrong?
Check the `HeadSegment` class. That is where I believe the error is being derived from.

Comment: So from some of the tests that I have run it appears as though they are only colliding by one pixel.

Comment: Why are they colliding?

Comment: Have you tried instead using all rectangles instead of Segments? And just update the rectangle of it everytime? Just get rid of the extension of Object all together, and then just use all of the same variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as near as I can tell, is the way you're updating the segment's positions. The way it's coded now, each new segment becomes the one directly behind the head, instead of the "safe" segments being the ones to follow the head.

The actual error is in the Segment.update function:

```
try:
    nextpos=segs[self.id+1]
    self.x=nextpos.prevpos[0]
    self.y=nextpos.prevpos[1]
except:
    self.x=head.prevpos[0]
    self.y=head.prevpos[1]
```

I switched the constructor logic so that the curid equals the index of the Segment in the segs list, then used this code:

```
if self.id < 1:
    self.x = head.prevpos[0]
    self.y = head.prevpos[1]
else:
    nextpos = segs[self.id-1]
    self.x = nextpos.prevpos[0]
    self.y = nextpos.prevpos[1]
```

This only collides when you run into yourself with a longer snake. The earliest segment I could force a collide was 19.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I switched to color detection instead of rect collision, it's a lot faster. But I will still implement your `Segment` class modification.

Comment: How did you get the index of `self` from segs?

Comment: The change was to the way you defined `curid`. In your code you put `self.id = curid +1` and then incremented `curid`. I initialized `curid` as 0, dropped the `curid + 1` so it looks like:
`self.id = curid
curid += 1`
That way `self.id` is the index of the segment.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much, that also fixed a graphical glitch, which I believe was cause by all the segments jumping back and forth between the head and current position. (: